# Place Pseudo Element Before Nested List inside LI

Tags: html, css

I'm working on some styling for a list and having trouble getting my Pseudo Element placed properly.

What I want the end result to look like is as follows:

```
send_id *string*
The unique identifier of the send
```

So I want the "content" (there will eventually be multiple types) to come right after the base content in the LI and not after the nested UL as well. I've been playing around with both before and after for a while now and can't get it right.

```css
.properties li,
.properties ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}

.properties ul {
  padding: 0;
}

ul.properties {
  padding: 0 28px;
}

.properties .string::after {
  content: "string";
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="properties">
  <li class="string">send_id
    <ul>
      <li>The unique identifier of the send</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="string">email
    <ul>
      <li>The destination email address</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="string">template
    <ul>
      <li>The name of the template used in the send</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="string">status
    <ul>
      <li>The delivery status of the send – either <code>unknown</code>, <code>scheduled</code>, <code>softbounce</code>, <code>hardbounce</code>, or <code>delivered</code></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="string">data_feed_url
    <ul>
      <li>Data feed used in the send</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="date">send_time
    <ul>
      <li>The time the message was sent (only available after a send completed)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>schedule_time
    <ul>
      <li>The time the message was scheduled (only if the message was scheduled in advance)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>open_time
    <ul>
      <li>The time the message was opened with images turned on (only if it was actually opened)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>click_time
    <ul>
      <li>The time the message was clicked (only if it was actually clicked)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sidenote: I realize it would be easier to just put the "content" as regular HTML but this is for Markdown based documentation and I am trying to make sure the special styling I'm added will be applied consistently, across the board by the people writing it.

Answer (score 2):

So here is the solution.

You can't create a pseudo to the parent element and expect it to work on its child element. What you need to do is, you must wrap the child element and add pseudo to it.

HTML:

```
<li class="string">
    <span>send_id</span> <!-- Wrap it -->
    <ul>
        <li>The unique identifier of the send</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.properties .string > span::after {
  content: "string";
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

This way you can have a flexibility over the number of characters throughout the content.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/h3jjc6bu/25/

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, was hoping to avoid that since it is difficult to use spans in markdown (without just adding HTML), but good to at least have verification it isn't possible!

Answer (score 0):

So what you have to do is to set the right `position` to `.string` and it's pseudo `::after`. To place it like you want, you must do follow changes in your css. Also put a span around the text to prevent the overlapping with position aboslute;

Set `position: relative;` on .string

```
.properties .string span {
  position: relative;
}
```

Than set `position: absolute;` to you pseudo `::after` and place it with `top: 0;` and `right: -50px;` next to the `send_id` like this:

```
.properties .string span::after {
  content: "string";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
}
```

Read how the `position` property works: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Below you can see the working snippet (I changed the color of the pseudo text so you can see it). Hope this helps

```css
.properties li,
.properties ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}

.properties ul {
  padding: 0;
}

ul.properties {
  padding: 0 28px;
}

.properties .string span {
  position: relative;
}

.properties .string span::after {
  content: "string";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -45px;
color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="properties">
  <li class="string"><span>send_id</span>
    <ul>
      <li>The unique identifier of the send</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="string"><span>email</span>
    <ul>
      <li>The destination email address</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="string"><span>template</span>
    <ul>
      <li>The name of the template used in the send</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="string"><span>status</span>
    <ul>
      <li>The delivery status of the send – either <code>unknown</code>, <code>scheduled</code>, <code>softbounce</code>, <code>hardbounce</code>, or <code>delivered</code></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="string"><span>data_feed_url</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Data feed used in the send</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="date"><span>send_time</span>
    <ul>
      <li>The time the message was sent (only available after a send completed)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>schedule_time</span>
    <ul>
      <li>The time the message was scheduled (only if the message was scheduled in advance)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: positioning absolute is not a good solution. it will and is overlapping the content. Check the last line.

Comment: @CodeMonk I updated the answer. He can solve it like this?

Comment: @CodeMonk Didn't see your answer while updating my own... they are quit similar... I like your's also!